# Reciprocal Figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a question,

Let T be the circle whose equation is $(x − 1)^2 + y^2 = 1.$ Considering T as an
envelope of lines, prove that its reciprocal figure is contained in the parabola
$2x − 1 + y^2 = 0.$ (Actually the two are equal, but you do not have to prove the
other inclusion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
*Fig. 1: The polars (tangent lines, in blue), their poles (red points) and the unit circle (green). An example: point (1/2,0) is the pole associated with the polar line with equation $x=2$ (case $\theta=0$; see below).*

Let us first explain what is called the **duality with respect to unit circle** (you use the adjective "reciprocal" instead, but it is certainly the same transform). This transform exchanges points and lines in the plane in a so-called **pole-polar correspondance**: to each line is associated a certain point; the line is called the polar, the point is its pole, and vice versa.

The way the pole is associated with its polar line is as follows: consider vector $\vec{OH}$ where $H$ is the projection of origin $O$ onto the line: take for pole the point $P$ on the half line defined by $OH$ such that

$$OP.\underbrace{OH}_p=1$$

With a different formulation, the polar coordinates of the pole $P$ are

$$(\tfrac{1}{p},\theta) \tag{1}$$

End of the recall.

---

The first step is to prove/check that the equation of the generic tangent to the circle is:

$$(L_{\theta}) \ \ \ x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta = p \ \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ \ p = 1+\cos \theta \tag{1}$$

(this form of line equation is called its "canonical form") where $(p,\theta)$ are the polar coordinates of $H$, the projection of the origin onto the line; otherwise said, length$(OH)=p$ and angle $(Ox,OH)=\theta$.

Therefore, using (1), the polar equation of the image curve is

$$r=\dfrac{1}{1+\cos \theta} \ \ \iff \ \ r+r \cos \theta=1\tag{2}$$

Now, turn to cartesian coordinates:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x=1 \tag{3}$$

which is equivalent, by squaring, to:

$$x^2+y^2=(1-x)^2 \tag{4}$$

giving the looked for curve with equation:

$$y^2=1-2x$$

Remark: Relationship (3) expresses that for a generic point $M$ on the parabola, we have

$$MO=MH$$

meaning that any point of the parabola is at the same distance from $O$ and to the vertical line $D$ with equation $x=1$. It means that $0$ is the focus and $D$ the directrix of the parabola; not surprisingly the vertex $(1/2,0)$ of the parabola is at half distance between them.

Matlab program for the figure:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;
> axis([-2,2,-2,2]);axis equal;grid on
> p=pi/10;set(gcf,'color','w');
> t=0:0.01:2*pi;
> plot(exp(i*t),'g');
> for k=1:20;
>    z=exp(i*p*k);
>    plot(z/(1+real(z)),'or','markerfacecolor','r')
>    plot(1+z*[(1+1.2i),(11.2i)]);
> end;
> plot([-2,2],[0,0],'k');
> plot([0,0],[-2,2],'k');
> ```

Comment: thanks a lottt.